# Can i know how to code keep run even if app is minimized in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Minimizing app while uploading files stops uploading.
I want to solve this

GetX controller or variables isn't recognized  on **"compute"**, **"isolate"** so they can not use.

**"Workmanager"** also not suitable.

Comment: You can check this package - https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen. 
- 

Try out code:

`@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    final isLock = await isLockScreen();
    if(!isLock){
       print('app inactive MINIMIZED!');
    }
    print('app inactive in lock screen!');
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    print('app resumed');
  }
}`

Comment: @Shub Thank you sir. I checking this awesome one. :)

Comment: it doesnt work my brain stopped no...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is android enable permission of battery optimization and correctly way to process.

flutter workmanager not related, don't try this.

Flutter's bad dev enviorment, scattered any libraries and plugins are not helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).